# Guardar documento en base de datos

Tags: java

Tengo un objeto: org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile

Me gustaria guardar este objeto en la base de datos(sqlserver y la tabla esta creada) mediante un insert

He intentado:

```
parseFile = file.getBytes()   => 
println parseFile             => Esto devuelve por consola algo asi [80, 75, 3, 4, 20, 0, 0...]
```

Al intentar hacer el insert, me da error

```
INSERT INTO Internal_tab("ID" ,"FATTACH") values ('1' ,'[80, 75, 3, 4, 20, 0, 0,]')
```

Mirando esta tabla, esta columna es varbinary(max), veo que la información guardar así: 0x255044462D312E36....

Error:

```
Implicit conversion from data type varchar(max) to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

Comment: @Benito-B pero creo que no necesito generar el documento, yo quiero que me cree la  consulta para ejecutarlo en sqlserve management

Comment: ¿E hiciste lo que te sugiere el mensaje?